# Laravel save or update many to many relationship with additional column

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4.2

I have a many to many relationship set up in laravel where I want to save user settings. A setting can be set from many users and a user can have many settings.

I have an additional field named "value" in the pivot table where I want to save the value set by the user.

Well, what I want is to create a new entry when there is no value for the particular user and setting. But if there is already a value it should get updated.

This is what I've tried:

```
$setting = Setting::find(1);
Auth::user()->settings()->save($setting,array('value' => 15));
```

As soon as I change the value to something else it automatically creates a new entry. But I'd like it to be updated. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the UpdateOrCreate method.

```
$setting = Setting::find(1);
Auth::user()->settings()->updateOrCreate($setting,array('value' => 15));
```

[Method Documentation](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.html#method_updateOrCreate)

Comment: Thanks! I'm still using laravel 4.2 and the method seems not to exist there. That's why I haven't found it. Think it's time to update then.